# Modifying pam with Ansible

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ansible, pam

As part of a new server setup, I provision `/etc/security/access.conf` with user/group and src IP addresses of allowed ssh logins. This requires enabling `pam_access` in the `/etc/pam.d/login` and `/etc/pam.d/sshd` files (on Ubuntu anyway)

It [seems](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/pamd_module.html) Ansible has a module for modifying some of these rules but I can't get it to work. A stipulation of the modules is: *"In order for a PAM rule to be modified, the type, control and module_path must match an existing rule."* Does that mean if a rule is commented out, the `pamd` module will not work for enabling that line?

This is my current playbook. I've tried removing the `with_items` line in the task and using `login` for the `name:` parameter but that doesn't seem to work either:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: modify pam_access in /etc/pam.d for sshd and login
      pamd:
        name   : "{{ item }}"
        type   : account
        control: required
        module_path: pam_access.so
      with_items:
        - login
        - sshd
```

And this the result of running it. It doesn't give me much to go on:

```
$ ansible-playbook tests/pam-access.yml -i 192.168.24.66,                                                             
SUDO password: 

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************************************

TASK [modify pam_access in /etc/pam.d for sshd and login] ************************************************************
ok: [192.168.24.66] => (item=login)
failed: [192.168.24.66] (item=sshd) => {"changed": false, "item": "sshd", "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 192.168.24.66 closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "\r\nTraceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_vzO7tZ/ansible_module_pamd.py\", line 691, in <module>\r\n    main()\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_vzO7tZ/ansible_module_pamd.py\", line 645, in main\r\n    pamd.load_rules_from_file()\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_vzO7tZ/ansible_module_pamd.py\", line 361, in load_rules_from_file\r\n    self.load_rules_from_string(stringline.replace(\"\\\\\\n\", \"\"))\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_vzO7tZ/ansible_module_pamd.py\", line 380, in load_rules_from_string\r\n    self.rules.append(PamdRule.rulefromstring(stringline))\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_vzO7tZ/ansible_module_pamd.py\", line 312, in rulefromstring\r\n    rule_type = result.group(1)\r\nAttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 1}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************
192.168.24.66              : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Answer (score 2):

Ended up going with `lineinfile`. If anyone has a better solution, would love to see it.

```
   ---
    - hosts: all
      gather_facts: False
      tasks:
        - name: un-comment or add pam_access in /etc/pam.d files
          lineinfile:
            path   : "{{ item }}"
            regexp : "#.*account.*required.*pam_access.so"
            line   : "account   required   pam_access.so"
            insertafter : ".*include.*common-auth"
            state  : present
          with_items:
            - /etc/pam.d/login
            - /etc/pam.d/sshd
```

Answer (score 1):

Run it with the -vvvv option to see why it failed. In the sshd and login files, find a rule that already exists, then you use the state parameter to tell it to insert your new rule before or after the existing one.  For example:

Try this format to create a new rule:

```
- name: modify pam_access in /etc/pam.d for sshd and login
  pamd:
    name: '{{ item }}'
    #Existing type, control, and module_path in sshd and login
    type: account
    control: required
    module_path: pam_nologin.so
    #New rule you want to add
    new_type: account
    new_control: required
    new_module_path: pam_access.so
    module_arguments: insert new args here, if applicable.  Remove if none.
    #Inserts rule before existing rule - can use after as well
    state: before 
  #loops through both files - if existing module exists in both.
  loop:
    - login
    - sshd
```

Or, you can find an existing rule and change the module/control:

```
 - name: Update pam_pwquality.so Rule Control 
  pamd:
    name: '{{ item }}'
    type: account
    control: required
    module_path: pam_nologin.so
    new_module_path: pam_pwquality.so
  loop:
    - login
    - sshd
```

Comment: finally some well explained information. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up running `pam-auth-update --force --enable profile mkhomedir sss tmpdir` as an ansible `command:` (obviously requires libpam-mkhomedir, libpam-tmpdir and libpam-sss installed prior)

The benefits of this method is that pam-auth-update does all the files it needs to, in a perfectly consistent way.

The problem with this method is that ansible always reports "changed".

I am looking for a nicer solution to check if the configuration is actually required or not, so as to make the task perfectly idempotent, but unfortunately the [only approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786263/only-check-whether-a-line-present-in-a-file-ansible) seems to be `slurp`ing all the remote files and checking them, or using a hack like `lineinfile:` with `check_mode: yes` and `changed_when: false` to see if the lines are present or not before running `pam-auth-update`.

My task:

```yaml
- name: enable pam modules (requires libpam-mkhomedir, libpam-tmpdir, libpam-sss installed)
  command: pam-auth-update --force --enable profile mkhomedir sss tmpdir
```